# How can i put a button after a body: Container?

Tags: flutter, dart, button, flutter-layout

i'm trying to develope an app with Flutter. I'm new at this :(

I can't add a button under the gridView.

This is my code:

```
body: Container(
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 47.0, top: 100),
        child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: GridView(children: [
          Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), color: Colors.grey),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
            Icon(Icons.router, size: 40, color: Colors.white),
            Text("DFGW", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20))
          ],),),
          Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), color: Colors.grey),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
            Icon(Icons.route_rounded, size: 40, color: Colors.white),
            Text("WAN", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20))
          ],),),
          Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), color: Colors.grey),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
            Icon(Icons.vpn_lock, size: 40, color: Colors.white),
            Text("VPN", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20))
          ],),),
          Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), color: Colors.grey),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
            Icon(Icons.language, size: 40, color: Colors.white),
            Text("INTERNET", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20))
          ],),),
        ],
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2, mainAxisSpacing: 10,                    crossAxisSpacing: 10),),
      )),
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        child: OutlinedButton(
          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            fixedSize: const Size(100, 100)
          ),
          child: Text("Start Checking", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black,),), 
                onPressed: () {},  
              ), 
        ),
```

[image]

This is my output right now.

I would like the button to be exactly under the grid, what can I do?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of good ways to do this. Check out the [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) widget and pay attention to properties MainAxisSize and CrossAxisAlignment

And also check out the [Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) and Expanded widgets

Id spend more time going through Flutter's widgets to really get familiar with the tools you have at hand for building UI with Flutter

All I did here was wrap your GridView with a column and throw a button below it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(const SwitchApp());

class ColorModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  Color color = Colors.green;
  void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class SwitchApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SwitchApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ColorModel>(
      create: (context) => ColorModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Switch Sample')),
          body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                  height: 300,
                  width: 300,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 47.0, top: 100),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: GridView(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Colors.grey),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(Icons.router, size: 40, color: Colors.white),
                              Text("DFGW",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Colors.grey),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(Icons.route_rounded,
                                  size: 40, color: Colors.white),
                              Text("WAN",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Colors.grey),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(Icons.vpn_lock,
                                  size: 40, color: Colors.white),
                              Text("VPN",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Colors.grey),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(Icons.language,
                                  size: 40, color: Colors.white),
                              Text("INTERNET",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 10),
                    ),
                  )),
              Center(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('button')))
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: Container(
            child: OutlinedButton(
              style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  fixedSize: const Size(100, 100)),
              child: Text(
                "Start Checking",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SwitchExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const SwitchExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<SwitchExample> createState() => _SwitchExampleState();
}

class _SwitchExampleState extends State<SwitchExample> {
  bool light = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Switch(
          // This bool value toggles the switch.
          value: light,
          activeColor: Colors.red,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            // This is called when the user toggles the switch.
            setState(() {
              light = value;
            });
            Provider.of<ColorModel>(context, listen: false)
                .setColor(value ? Colors.green : Colors.blue);
          },
        ),
        MyText()
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyText({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ColorModel>(builder: (context, state, _) {
      return Text('Change my color', style: TextStyle(color: state.color));
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want add button to just below of gridview children if I am understand right?. If then you can wrap your Container with Column and put button as a second child like this,

```
body: Column(
      children:[
         Container(
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 47.0, top: 100),
        child: // your grid view..
        ),
        YourButtonWidget(), // and your button 
   ],
),
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was right too!